# How change USB connection form MTP to PTP?

Tags: settings, usb-connection-mode, broken-screen

I have a broken-screen Android phone (Lenovo Tab 2 A7 30-HC) ,
and I wanna monitor it's screen to my PC using "Vysor",an extension of Chrome, USB-debugging is On, but my problem is that "USB connection" is set on MTP , and it should be on PTP( for monitoring and install application through adb ).

my only option is, connect a mouse to my phone and then do it blindly:)
my question is, where can i change this option in settings ?

or can anyone suggest me a better solution for monitoring?

Comment: What's the OS you're running on your tablet? while USB Debugging is ON Vysor will cast your phone screen on the PC, where is the problem?

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui it's running android 5.01 . Vysor was work fine when USB connection was on PTP, One day I change it to MTP to transfer some files between PC and Mobile, and after that Vysor doesn't work anymore! I think Vysor need to set on PTP , because I'm also an android developer and when I want to deploy my applications to my phone using Android Studio, I must set connection to PTP.

Comment: I can't understand until now, if USB debugging is working now or not, but try this from CMD shell type: **adb shell setprop sys.usb.config "ptp,adb"**

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui Thank u, but no chance. when I try **adb shell** it echo "erroer: closed", and also when I try **adb devices** it doesn't show anything! I'm sure USB debugging is on. I said it doesn't work if not set to PTP, for now adb doesn't work ( i dunno why! maybe in other phones it doesn't matter what USB connection is, but mine it matter).

Comment: Do you have a Custom Recovery (TWRP/CWM) or Stock Recovery on your tablet?

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui it's recovery mode is <3e>

Comment: That's the stock recovery. But, to the original problem: connect the device via USB, and tap the notification which says "connected via MTP". That should bring you to a screen where you can chose PTP again.

Comment: @Izzy Thank u, But my problem is screen-touch doesn't work, and I must connect a mouse for interaction , so can't connect a USB (to pop USB notification up) and mouse at same time haha:) can I ?! where can I find USB connection in settings?

Comment: Oh, missed the `broken-screen` tag, sorry. And yes, using a hub was reported successfully in some cases. Also take a look at our [broken-screen tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info), useful stuff linked there.

Comment: @Izzy OH YES! that's it! I didn't know anything about hub! I think it should work!Let me buy and test it after our Holidays ,and will Accept your answer if it works( if my Tablet support it haha:) ) Thank u very much friend:)

Comment: Let us know the outcome, so I can make my proposal an answer to accept for you if it worked out :) Fingers crossed!